# Clustered NIFI, Only one node is working

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm using NIFI in a clustered mode with two nodes, and I have noticed that only one node that do all the work.

[image]
[image]

Any idea why is that ? and how can I make nifi2 do some of the processing of the dataflow ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends how data is coming in to your cluster. It is up to you as the data flow designer to create an approach that allows the data to be partitioned across your cluster for processing.

See this post for an overview of strategies to do this:

https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/16120/how-do-i-distribute-data-across-a-nifi-cluster.html

Comment: My use case is really simple I have a webservice created in Nifi1 with a HandleHTTPRequest and I try to distribute the flowcontent on success of this processor through my Nifi1 and Nifi2 

My HandleHttpRequest is run only on NIFI1 and all the other processor are run on All Nodes, so I assume Nifi2 should have access to a part of the flowcontent or it does not work like that ? 

After reading the article, I need a load balancer above my HDF cluster and the handleHttpRequest run on both nodes ?

Comment: Yea if you are providing a web-service via HandleHttpRequest, you likely want to stick a load balancer in front and have your clients post to the URL of the load balancer. Once data is on a given node, the data is only processed on that node unless you use the site-to-site back-to-self approach shown in the ListHDFS example, which I don't think makes sense for your use-case.

Comment: Surprisingly HAproxy was really easy to configure. Thank you